# Map images path to another path in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, virtual-directory

The web application located in `"D:ApplicationName"` and host in `IIS` .

In the application have a `images folder`.Over time,the folder increase quickly.

So,How to map the images folder to "E:\images"

HTML Sometimes like:

```
<img alt="" src="~/images/a.jpg" />(which point to "E:\images\a.jpg")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a url rewrite, consider setting up a virtual directory in IIS. Name it `images`, and point it to the `E:\images` folder.